Let f and g be functions such that $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x},g'(x)=\cos^2(3x)+1,g(0)=4$. Resolve $(f∘g)'(0),(g∘f)'(0)$
I resolve the first one:
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}(\cos^2(3·0)+1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and second composite function I think it can't be done, the derivative of f(x) cant be evaluated to 0, here is my resolution:
$(\cos^2(3·1)+1)·\frac{1}{2\sqrt{0}}$
What do you think?

@ShyamalSayak Thanks!!
